# File ended while scanning use of \newrgbcolorx

Tags: errors

I am working on a LaTeX document for poster presentation. I use: Mac Version 10.8.5 and TexShop version 3.50. The code I use is here:

```
    \documentclass[portrait,a0,final]{a0poster}    
    \usepackage{mathrsfs,multicol,pstricks,pst-node}    
    \usepackage{pst-grad,graphicx,palatino}    
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,pifont,bbm}

    \newcommand{\OlliFrameboxA}[1]{
    \psframebox[framearc=0.3,linewidth=2pt,linecolor=green,
     fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=yolk,gradend=white,gradmidpoint=0.5]{
     #1
     }
     }

   %%%%%%%%%
   \input{PosterA.def}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
begin{document}
%%%%%%%%% TITLE STUFF %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\PosterTitleA}{
xxxxx
}
\newcommand{\PosterTitleB}{
yyyyy
}



\end{document}
```

This is call up command for PosterA.def

```
\newcommand{\TitleFntSize}{\veryHuge\bf}
\newcommand{\AuthorFntSize}{\huge}
\newcommand{\AffFntSize}{\Large}
\newcommand{\TextFntSize}{\normalsize}                                                     
\setlength{\textwidth}{80.1cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.8cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{115.9cm}
%%%%% PAGE SETUP A1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt} % RULE BETWEEN COLUMNS
\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm} % SEPARATION BETWEEN COLUMNS                                                             \makeatletter
\newenvironment{tablehere} % THIS IS TO INSERT TABLES
  {\def\@captype{table}}
  {}

\newenvironment{figurehere} % THIS IS TO INSERT FIGURES
  {\def\@captype{figure}}
  {}
\makeatother

\newrgbcolor{lightcyan}{.30 .86 .89}
\newrgbcolor{orange}{1.0 .60 .00}
\newrgbcolor{lightblue}{.30 .86 .89}
\newrgbcolor{orange}{1.0 .60 .00}
\definecolor{DeepSkyBlue1}{rgb}{0.00 0.75 1.00}
\newrgbcolor{deepskyblue2}{rgb}{0.00,0.70 0.93}
\newrgbcolor{yolk}{1.0 0.90 0.0}
\definecolor{cornflowerblue}{rgb}{0.39, 0.58, 0.93}
\newrgbcolor{olli}{0.39 0.58 .93}
```

### When I tryed to compile the tex file I got the following error.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./A.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(./a0poster.cls
Document Class: a0poster 2004/01/31 v1.22b a0poster class (GK, MW)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./a0size.sty))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex)
`PSTricks' v2.43  <2013/05/12> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-node/pst-node.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex
 v1.27, 2013/04/12))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-grad/pst-grad.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-grad/pst-grad.tex
`pst-grad' v1.06, 2006/11/27 (tvz,dg,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/palatino.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty)
(./PosterA.def)
Runaway argument?
\newrgbcolor {cornflowerblue}{0.39 0.58 .93} \newrgbcolor {olli}{0.39\ETC.
./Houches.tex:19: File ended while scanning use of \newrgbcolorx.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.19 \input{PosterA.def}

? 
Process aborted
```

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: The code that you posted does not cause the problem. Please edit your question to include an example that does reproduce the problem. Without this, it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Beside the need of an MWE, you should rephrase the title of your Question. Like this, it will not help anybody in future. Thank you.

Comment: There is a brace missing in your PosterA.def, and the error message even *shows* you where.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Ulrike Ficsher there is an error also in PosterA.def This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode (./PosterA.def LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded. ./PosterA.def:71: Undefined control sequence. l.71 \definecolor {lightblue}{rgb}{0.68,0.85,0.90} ?

Comment: Without knowing what's in `posterA.def` it's not possible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @egreg I just wrote the details of PosterA.def above

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're using different syntaxes for defining colors; the fact is that you get confused:

```
\newrgbcolor{lightcyan}{.30 .86 .89}
\newrgbcolor{orange}{1.0 .60 .00}
\newrgbcolor{lightblue}{.30 .86 .89}
\newrgbcolor{orange}{1.0 .60 .00}
\definecolor{DeepSkyBlue1}{rgb}{0.00, 0.75, 1.00}% <---- commas needed
\newrgbcolor{deepskyblue2}{0.00 0.70 0.93}% <---- no {rgb} and no comma
\newrgbcolor{yolk}{1.0 0.90 0.0}
\definecolor{cornflowerblue}{rgb}{0.39, 0.58, 0.93}
\newrgbcolor{olli}{0.39 0.58 .93}
```

Comment: I change it but still the same error

Comment: @Herman --- then something not shown in your example must be causing the problem. egreg's solution works (provided the missing backslash before `begin{document}` is inserted).

Comment: @lan Thompson still the same error with File ended while scanning use of \newrgbcolorx.

Comment: @herman --- If I apply egreg's solution to your example it works.

Comment: @lan Thompson the same eroor-File ended while scanning use of \newrgbcolorx.
<inserted text> 
         \par 
l.19 \input{PosterA.def}

Comment: @Herman You probably have a similar error in `PosterHouches.def`, but since my crystal ball is at the office and I'm headed home, I can't consult it. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg It's PosterA.def in my file.